# IOleClientSite implementation for IE11 loses WM_KEYUP ans WM_KEYDOWN events

Tags: internet-explorer, com, dom-events

I have Internet Explorer 11 embedded in a C++ application.  I have implemented the following interfaces:

IDocHostUIHandler

This passes all methods to the original implementation except for GetExternal which returns my implementation of an external object.

IOleClientSite

This passes all methods through to the original implementation.  The QueryInterface implementation returns my IDocHostUIHandler when requested.  It also returns itself for IUnknown. 
I have tried passing requests for other interfaces through to the original IOleClientSite implementation but this has not effect on the problem described below.

I have also attached an event sink to the current document for the purpose of handling and firing DOM events but I am sure that this is not part of the problem.

The issue is that the browser is ignoring WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYCHAR messages (these are never fired as DOM events) but does respond to WM_CHAR messages (which are fired as DOM keypress events.)
If I do not insert my IOleClientSite implementation then these events are handled properly.  I am therefore, fairly certain that there is some omission in my implementation of IOleClientSite.
It is my understanding that I have to implement IOleClientSite in order to provide an implementation IDocHostUIHandler (i.e. there is no other way to inject my implementation of that interface.)
Why are my WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYCHAR messages being ignored?

Note that everything else is working correctly.  I can call methods on my external object from JavaScript, I can receive DOM events in my event sink and I can fire events into the DOM.

For what it’s worth, the underlying site is provided by a QT 3.3 QAxWidget.  I am aware that this is well out of date; this work is ultimately intended to remove the dependency on this old code.  Nevertheless, the browser behaves properly when my IOleClientSite is removed so there is no reason to suspect problems in the QAxWidget implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WM\_KEYUP and WM\_KEYDOWN messages lost in embedded IE11 control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977258/wm-keyup-and-wm-keydown-messages-lost-in-embedded-ie11-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination of two problems.  The QAxWidget containing the browser needs to have TranslateKeyEvent implemented in a derived class.  Also, you cannot provide an implementation of an IOleClientSite because Qt3.3 is broken and internally it will continue to reference it's own implementation instead of the new one.  I had to modify QAxWidget to add a setDocHostUIHandler function and modified its QueryInterface to return this.  Thus the default IOleClientSite will then return the correct interface for IID_IDocHostUIHandler.